# ETH smart contract deposit and withdrawal functionality - multiple addresses?

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, exchanges, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I have an ERC721 smart contract with basic functionality.

When the user deposits this ERC721 token, I generate for him a new eth address. For example using

```
account_pass = random_text()
Account.enable_unaudited_hdwallet_features()
account, mnemonic_phrase = Account.create_with_mnemonic(account_pass)
```

So, for example, I have 10 of my ERC721 tokens on my 10 different addresses.

Now, some user wants to withdraw 25 tokens.

1. Will this result in 3 transactions meaning I will have to pay transaction fees 3 times by 3 different accounts each?
2. The second possibility is running the `setApprovalForAll` function when creating a new deposit address, thus allowing to control ERC721 tokens of deposit account from some my main address. This function, however, requires having some ETHs on my new deposit address.
3. Or is it possible to send ERC721 tokens from multiple accounts to one account with 1 transaction where the transaction fee payer will be also 1 account?
4. Or can I configure my Ethereum node (dedicated) to pay the transaction fees for transactions made via my node?
5. Or should I allow the smart contract owner (me) to send ERC721 tokens from any account to any destination?

How can I implement not so costly deposit and withdrawal functionality?
I would like to pay the transaction fees just from my 1 account.

P.S. I use Python Web3 + eth_account

Smart Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC721, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Burnable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "MTK") {}

    function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
        _safeMint(to, tokenId);
    }

    function _burn(uint256 tokenId) internal override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage) {
        super._burn(tokenId);
    }

    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        override(ERC721, ERC721URIStorage)
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return super.tokenURI(tokenId);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is not enough detail in this question to make an answer. You will need to post your complete contract source code to get a response on this public forum.

Comment: @WilliamEntriken I have added the source code, but it is so basic, that its absence shouldn't be of a great importance